# Get a list of all rcus available in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle12c, weblogic12c, rcu

In our development environment, developers have created too many RCU schemas for Weblogic Domain. Many of these developers have now left the organization, and we need to circulate the list of RCUs the DBA would be deleting, so that people can inform us in advance if they are using a particular RCU schema.
So is there any easy way of finding all the RCU in Oracle 12c or Weblogic RCU tools?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing which comes to my mind is to launch the RCU utility in GUI. Select drop repository and provide the DB details. Once verification is done, you can see all Prefixes in drop down and from there you can drop the unwanted RCU.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it brother :). We had already thought of this solution as our last resort. We just wanted to know, if there was an easier way. Thank you for your time and suggestion :D